# Delicious .NET API with C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, delicious-api

I would like to create a C# application (.net 2.0 due to the API) to post new bookmarks to Delicious. I found a library: http://netlicious.sourceforge.net/ but I can't find any sample files. I added the DLL to my references and enter the following code:

```
Delicious.Connection.Username = "e-mail";
Delicious.Connection.Password = "password";

Delicious.Post.Add (url, description, extended, tags, date, replace, shared);
```

But i get an exception at the POST method: "The server is not responding.   ServiceUnavailable"
What's the problem? I can use Delicious from firefox.

Comment: What is your URL you are entering?

Comment: http://fresh-social-media-news.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a Yahoo email address? The developer [says](http://www.procanta.com/) :

> Netlicious will continue working for users who have a del.icio.us
>   account. But, users will not be able to login with a Yahoo account.